# NullPointerException at TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean encountered after updating from WLS 12.1.3 to WLS 12.2.1

Tags: jsf, el, weblogic12c

We have just upgraded our Weblogic Server from 12.1.3 to 12.2.1.4.
And I am getting an NPE after the first forward() using RequestDispatcher.

I tried the following solutions after reading some materials from the Internet:

1. Put "-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=true" in JAVA_OPTIONS of start script
   *I read that EL 3.3.0 changed the way it handles null so I tried this but it did not work*
2. Upgrade from JSF 2.1.28 to JSF 2.2.0 in WEB-INF/lib of my webapp
   *I get the same error*
3. Upgrade to el-api-2.2.1-b03.jar and then added these lines in my weblogic.xml -

```
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.el.*</package-name> <----------------------------
    </prefer-application-packages>
    
    <prefer-application-resources>
        <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name>
    <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>javax.el.*</resource-name> <----------------------------
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
    <resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.FacesConfigResourceProvider</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>
```

-- This gave me a brand-new java.lang.LinkageError so I removed the 2 lines again

4. I have also updated IceFaces EE 3.3.0 from PA3 to PA7
   *I get the same error even after updating*

Could anyone please let me know what I should check next or anything I may have missed?
I have only started learning weblogic.xml configuration for this task so please feel free to treat me like a newbie and point out any rookie mistakes. Thanks!  =)

Below is the latest log entry showing the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean(TagAttributeImpl.java:150)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.isDisabled(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:81)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyAttachedObject(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:113)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyNested(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:212)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:88)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:972)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
> ~[jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]   at
> javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
> ~[jsf-api-2.2.0.jar:2.2]  ... 32 more

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by editing my weblogic.xml to remove the items under the following:
`<prefer-application-packages>` and
`<prefer-application-resources>`.

I am still not 100% sure why it worked. The `<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>` is telling WLS to get its packages from the built-in bundle. So I am guessing the packages in the app's WEB-INF/lib that were previously used as override were no longer correct after the upgrade.